# display a Textbox by clicking CheckBox array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I displayed a list of item with Checkbox. I want a user to Check the items he want and enter the quantity he wants for the item. I hid the Quantity Textbox (txtQty) using CSS. I want if you click an Item, the corresponding txtQty will appear for you to enter the Quantity you want.
I am using CodeIgniter. So I have sucdessfully pulled data fro MySQL through the Model to the View and displayed it, as shown in the interface image attached. I am using Jquery to do the hide and show.
[The Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJh24.png)

My Code:
**2. View Code (PHP)**

```
<table class="card1 table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive" style="height: 350px; overflow: scroll">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SN</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Tick</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $i=0; foreach($it as $r): $i++; ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?=$r['Item'];?></td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="<?=$r['Item']?>" id="jj">
                </label>
            </td>
            </td>
            <td> 
                <input type="number" name="qty[]" id="tx" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?=$r['CostPrice']?>" />
            </td>
        </tr> 
        <?php endforeach?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="submit" name="btnub" value="Send Order" class="btn btn-warning card1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**3. my Jquery Code.**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#jj').change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $('#tx').show();
            } else {
                $('#tx').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

4. I will also like to know how to now retrieve only selected Items, and quantity at the Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two main issues here. Firstly your PHP loop is creating HTML with repeated `id` attributes. This is invalid as `id` *have* to be unique within the DOM. Change those to classes instead.

As a corollary you can no longer use the `id` to select the `#tx` element. You'll need to select it by it's class using DOM traversal to relate it to the specific checkbox which was changed.

Also note that the `if` condition can be simplified by using `toggle()`, and that your HTML has an additional `</td>` which can be removed.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.jj').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.tx').toggle(this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="card1 table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive" style="height: 350px; overflow: scroll">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SN</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Tick</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="100" class="jj"></label></td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="qty[]" class="tx" style="display: none" />
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="50" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="100" class="jj"></label></td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="qty[]" class="tx" style="display: none" />
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="50" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Fizz</td>
      <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="100" class="jj"></label></td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="qty[]" class="tx" style="display: none" />
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="50" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Buzz</td>
      <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="100" class="jj"></label></td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="qty[]" class="tx" style="display: none" />
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="50" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <input type="submit" name="btnub" value="Send Order" class="btn btn-warning card1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Rory. It worked. I am able to select and the Quantitybox appeared at selection.

Comment: However, the problems now is:  How to sum the prices on the corresponding Items selected by the User and How to get the Amount: NOTE-> Amount = (sum of Quantities) * (sum of Prices)